# Orienting text on the back of a flipped card?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

From a couple of previous StackOverFlow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656071/how-to-flip-a-uiview-around-the-x-axis-while-simultaneously-switching-subviews) and this example on github [CA360](https://github.com/neror/CA360/), I've managed to simulate a flipping card with an image on the "front" and text on the back.  However, the text on the back of the card is upside down and I only got it to center horizonatally.  How can I orient the text properly and center it vertically on my card?

Card front:

[image]

Card back (How to orient and center text vertically?):

[image]

**[Update]**

I set the opacity on my top layer to 0.5 then I got the idea to just "pre-flip" the back layer so that when the actual flip happened that it would just reset it back to normal.

[image]

My "pre-flip" looks like this:

```
cardBack.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Pre-flip card
```

Now I just need to find a built-in way to vertical setting or do it the hard way... Half the distance...font height... plus...

Set up card container with 2 layers
([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656071/how-to-flip-a-uiview-around-the-x-axis-while-simultaneously-switching-subviews/9658527#9658527)):

```
    - (void)loadView {
        UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        self.view = myView;

        cardContainer = [CATransformLayer layer];
        cardContainer.frame = CGRectMake(300, 250, 200, 150);


        CALayer *cardFront  = [CALayer layer];
        cardFront.frame     = cardContainer.bounds;
        cardFront.zPosition = 5;   // Higher than the zPosition of the back of the card
        cardFront.contents  = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ben"].CGImage;
        cardFront.opacity = 0.5;

        [cardContainer addSublayer:cardFront];

        /*
         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209734/add-text-to-calayer
         */

        CATextLayer *cardBack  = [CATextLayer layer];
        cardBack.string = @"Hello";
        cardBack.frame     = cardContainer.bounds;
        cardBack.zPosition = 4;
        cardBack.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
        cardBack.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
        CFTypeRef *font = (CFTypeRef *)CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Times"), 48, NULL);
        cardBack.font = font;
        [cardContainer addSublayer: cardBack];

        [self.view.layer addSublayer:cardContainer];

    }
```

Code borrowed from another SOF question to flip card:

```
    - (void) flipCard {
    //    [self.flipTimer invalidate];
    //    if (flipped){
    //        return;
    //    }
        NSLog(@"Count=%d", count);
        id animationsBlock = ^{
    //        self.backView.alpha = 1.0f;
    //        self.frontView.alpha = 0.0f;
    //        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.frontView];
    //        flipped = YES;
            NSLog(@"Flipping...");
            CALayer *layer = cardContainer;
            CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
           rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 500;

            if (count == 0) {


                rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, M_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            } else {  // flip it back to image

                rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            }
            layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
        };
        count = (count + 1) % 2;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:animationsBlock
                         completion:nil];

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of the UIView class method:

- (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:`(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`

You would have two views, the front and the back. both can be in your nib. With this call, you can flip from one view to the other view with almost no effort.

EDIT: I did look at your code. Note that anchorPoint, position, and bounds all play together, but you can still use frame. Its interesting (dare I say fun) to play with changing one and seeing how the others change.

What I ended up doing is comment out all setting of position and frame, and essentially set the text box frame as I would with a UIView (width of large view minus width of small view divided by 2,etc):

```
cardBackText.frame = CGRectMake((200-100)/2, (150-30)/2, 100,30); // 200, 150
NSLog(@"position=%@ anchorPoint=%@ bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cardBackText.position),NSStringFromCGPoint(cardBackText.anchorPoint),NSStringFromCGRect
```

The log printed this out:

```
position={100, 75} anchorPoint={0.5, 0.5} bounds={{0, 0}, {100, 30}}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, and I've implemented it.  I'd like to do it with the CALayer.  I'm hoping to do some more interesting stuff in the very near future, especially with CATextLayer.

Comment: I'm closing this question early.  It's not the right answer, but you get the 50 points anyway.

Comment: Now you made me feel bad? Just keep in mind that so much of Quartz is upside down relative to UIKit (historical). I found a nice window flipper for the mac, LemurFlip (google it). If your really want to get this working per your above code I'm willing to help.

Comment: I think vertical alignment is the only thing that I need.  From what I've read though, it's a bit of work.  For now I might just use the two views solution.  I guess they're light weight enough.

Comment: Well, if you want to spin a little project and put it on DropBox, I'd be glad to play around with it. If I cannot fix it I have friends who owe me :-)

Comment: Does this work? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/palmv4t88y6v01s/uJ5_FjX793 Most code is in View1Controller -> loadView Clicking any key in view causes it to flip.

Comment: I can see it all but cannot seem to download it. Can you make a xip file and put it in your pubic folder? Thanks

Comment: I put the code on github too. Table Cell "One" is the right view: https://github.com/melling/CAStoryboard

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14600/discussion-between-m-x-and-david-h)