# Adding Flip Animation to UIImageView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to add a flip animation to an UIImageView in Xamarin. The flip animation does work, however, it flips the entire root view. I only want the UIImageView to flip, not the entire screen. Here's what I have:

```
    back = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("CardBack.jpg"));
    back.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    back.Frame = new RectangleF(110, 20, 100, 100);
    RootView.AddSubview(back);

    front = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("jack.jpg"));
    front.Frame = new RectangleF(110, 20, 100, 100);
```

The transition code, which occurs when the user touches the image, is as followed:

```
    UIImageView.Transition(
        fromView: back,
        toView: front,
        duration: .5,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromTop | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            completion: () => { Console.WriteLine("transition complete"); });
```

How would I just flip the UIImageView, rather than the entire UIView?

Comment: I don’t know Xamarin.. but for Objective-C you can check http://phildow.net/2012/05/31/flip-an-image-in-uiimageview-using-uiview-transitionwithview/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656071/how-to-flip-a-uiview-around-the-x-axis-while-simultaneously-switching-subviews

Answer (score 0):

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
                 }
                 completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for flip animation on your imageview

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"bucketsOff" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:(id)self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.ImageView cache:YES];
//animate off screen
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

AnimationTransition types are:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewAnimationTransition) {
UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
```

};